# What are the good practices, to maintain a low memory usage for background services?

Tags: android, background-service, memory-optimization

I have implemented a simple background service class which contains a Toast message only. But its is taking around 16-20mb, though there are other processes which takes only 1-3mb.

This is my code for my service class

```
public class BackgroundClipListener extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Here are the memory usages.

[image: NO Other Apps Running]    [image: List of Other Process]    [image: My Service]

If anyone can describe me why my service is taking so much memory or how can I imrove my code, it will be very helpfull.

Comment: problem is not with service, its with your main code.and 17mb i dont think is a problem at all

Comment: No 17MB is not a problem but there are other services which performs certain tasks though they takes low memory. I wanted to know how can I improve my code. My service contains nothing special, only a toast is displayed @MohammedAtif

Comment: as told earlier, problem is not the service, 17mb is taken by the app. there is a difference between service and process bdw. and if u r talking about 1mb of google process, then one thing you must know is most of the google codes run along with OS hence you dont see much burden on individual google apps.

Comment: Actually I'm also adding a Firebase Database listener as a background service, which takes 41mb in total. So is it ok? Please tell me that I should care about memory usage by my services or not. And thanks for your quick responses. @MohammedAtif

Comment: yes you can add the listener, just dont forget to remove the listeners and destroy them in on destroy of your service

Comment: Sure I'm doing that

Comment: Can you tell me if I use `clipMgr.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener()...);` this syntax to add a listener den how should I detach it ? @MohammedAtif